# Reduce image file size from camera crop

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, base64

I am trying to implement the best approach to reduce a file, basicly my app is about plants, i need high quality images, so the first thing i did was use a external library to crop images in thumbnail(so i can mantain aspect ratio) i use 1:1 thumnbnail format.

Every time i take a picture and if everything is ok on activityResult, it calls the builded crop library so i can cut and get the uri, like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        dateTimer = getTime();

        Log.d("codig",String.valueOf(requestCode));

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("resultOK","resultOK");
            CropImage.activity(data.getData())
                    .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                    .setInitialCropWindowPaddingRatio(0)
                    .setActivityTitle("Corte a foto")
                    .setActivityMenuIconColor(R.color.nephritis)
                    .setRequestedSize(300, 300, CropImageView.RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_INSIDE)
                    .start(this);
        }
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = result.getUri();
                Bitmap pic = null;
                try {
                    pic = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                path = saveToInternalStorage(pic);
                Log.d("caminho",path);
                showDetailsDialog(data);
            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
                Log.d("pict12",error.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

as you guys can see i have a setRequestSize method there, where i reduce the size of the image (this works, but just sometimes, the text i send as base64 is still to big.

i convert the uri to bitmap and save it on the device file, on next acitivty i get the file

```
private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Create imageDir
        File mypath=new File(directory,"captured.jpg");

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
            // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return directory.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

so on next activity i get it like this:

```
private void loadImageFromStorage(String path)
    {

        try {
            File f=new File(path, "captured.jpg");
            Log.d("filehe",f.toString());
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

i get the b(bitmap) and covert him to byte[] after to base64(what my server asks for)

```
 byte[] capture = encodeImage(b);
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(capture,1);
        Log.d("encodedImage",encodedImage);

        params.put("base64", encodedImage);
```

the problem here is that i need to preserve the quality of the image and i can't get the quality without increasing the heavyness on my server, can't i compress it somehow? i do it on the file but doesn't work

Comment: `encodeImage(b);` We cannot see what is done with bitmap b. Do you encode to jpg again? If you want to sent a jpg file to a server then why are you messing around with a bitmap? Just take the bytes of the file. Encode the bytes base64 and send to server.

Comment: If you have a jpg file you cannot compress it any further without loosing quality or resolution.

Comment: tnks greenapps but how can i not loose too much quality? i mean what is the best way=